# Classic story about a rainmaking pilot over LA

Tags: story-identification

The playful story I'm looking for must be from the 1940s or 1950s, and may be playing in the late 20th century. A young pilot skillfully seeds clouds over fields growing the area of today's LA suburbs. He uses his knowledge of the area's topography and meteorology, being informed about the changing weather from a ground station by radio.

He is good enough to get a young man on the ground wet who is flirting with his girl, and the girl is amused.

Overall a fun read, not least because of the names of crop-growing places which are today part of the sprawl.

Comment: Why the close votes? I searched fo about an hour with varying keywords (I didn't know the exact title, to begin with), but there are lots of stories and novels called *Rainmaker* none of which seemed to match my memory. I only post here as a last resort ;-) -- and I'm among the ones who are super grateful for the support I can get here. As an aside, I'm sending a printout to a young cousin of mine who has joined the U.S. army a few weeks ago. He writes that books are forbidden as "contraband" during basic training, I'll send him story printouts :-). )[Any idea why they forbid books!?]

Comment: I believe the close votes are from people who wrong-headedly think the story isn't science fiction because there are no blasters or Klingons, I guess. Don't let it bother you. Hope your cousin enjoys the story. I enjoyed answering your question, hope you have more like that.

Comment: About how I found the story: instead of the evil Google, I used an advanced title search at isfdb.org, looking for English language short fiction from that period with "rain" in the title, and got real lucky. Didn't find John Reese's "Rainmaker" on the web, but I happen to have a tattered copy of *Tomorrow, the Stars* in my vast accumulation of stuff. I must have had it for 50 years, but I don't believe I ever read that particular story before now.

Comment: @user14111 I actually have a print copy of Heinlein's "Tomorrow, the Stars" inherited from my late father-in-law! Now that I knew what to look for I found it, and it may have been where I encountered it.-- Oh, and the search strategy is useful!

Comment: on the face of it - it doesn't sound like sci-fi at all as asked in the question, so I can understand the votes to close. Now - when the answer turns out to be rainmaking written about in 1949...well...cloud seeding had apparently already been tested a few years prior and considered much earlier. It's borderline to me, but if Heinlein included it in an anthology, who am I to argue? :)

Comment: @NKCampbell Is Bradbury's [*The Murderer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Murderer) not SF just because the world depicted is resembling our own, perhaps a little quaint? Reese's story is fiction involving technology playing in the then future. If that is not SF I don't know what is. (Granted, our hero only flies a few thousand feet, but crossing the Karman line is not a criterion for SF! ;-) )

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I didn't spend much time yesterday looking for an online copy of "Rainmaker" as I knew I had a paper copy of *Tomorrow, the Stars*. Actually, the issue of the *SatEvePost* where the story first appeared is in the Internet Archive. I added a link to my answer.

Comment: @NKCampbell I don't understand how it's *not* science fiction. It's a speculative story about the effects of a then-new technology, seen in the story in a more advanced form than it existed at the time it was written. (This seems perfectly obvious to me from the question also, though I suppose if someone didn't know what "seeds clouds" meant they might not realise it.)

Comment: @user14111 Thanks for the link! It is interesting to see the publishing context of 1949 and it was fun to look through the magazine. I liked the sympathetic report about a "negro" college and the steam engine adventure story; I also liked some of the ads.The overall optimism exuding the issue seemed almost like SF in itself. it is easy to see how one can write such stories at the time.

Comment: I agree @Nathaniel - *in hindsight*. Now that we know what the story actually is. But if the question had asked "I recall reading a story about a short person who went up a mountain to throw some jewelry into a hole" there is nothing * in that description * that indicates that it is scifi or fantasy - see what I mean. That's all I'm saying. As described,  I can understand how people might have felt it was realistic fiction. The answer of course makes it clear that at the time of writing it was clearly science fiction

Comment: @NKCampbell surely *any* story about successful cloud seeding is science fiction. I don't see how it could be otherwise. You don't need the answer to see that.

Comment: ...cloud seeding isn't science fiction @Nathaniel :) Again, I didn't vote to close nor downvoted - I'm merely trying to say that I *understand* why *some* people would read the question as written and presume it lacked any substantial amount of science fiction (prior to knowing the answer) - have a good day

Comment: @NKCampbell cloud seeding *that works for weather control* is science fiction.

Comment: but again...@Nathaniel - that isn't what is indicated in the original description (imo)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

["Rainmaker"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81726), a short story by [John Reese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_H._Reese); originally published in the February 19, 1949 issue of [*The Saturday Evening Post*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saturday_Evening_Post), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/the-saturday-evening-post-1949-02-19/page/n25/mode/1up); reprinted in the anthology [*Tomorrow, the Stars*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?278382) edited by [Robert A. Heinlein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein) et al.

The story is set in Southern California in the late 1960s. Bill Lawson is a licensed professional rainmaker:

> Things had changed a lot since scientists first seeded clouds with pellets of dry ice, making them discharge their moisture in the form of artificial rain, twenty-odd years ago. Bill was a kid of eight when he watched a little cub plane make three passes at a cirro-cumulus formation over a grass fire in the Santa Monica Mountains, just about the time the Japanese surrendered—some time in the middle forties, anyway.
>
> It didn't work, and the fire burned itself out, but the kid of eight knew what he wanted to be when he grew up. A rainmaker. Now, at twenty-eight, William Lawson had held California Precipitation Permit No. 1 for six years, ever since the state started granting them under the Supreme Court decision.
>
> The permit meant he was a skilled airplane pilot. It meant he had two years of college meteorology. It meant he could tell you at any given time what crops were in what growing stages, and where. It meant he could tell you, without looking at the charts, each of the two dozen two-day to five-day periods during a hot, dry California summer when a rain would do a lot of good for everyone and harm to no one. Charts? He had written most of them himself.

After completing his deliveries to the area farmers, he buzzes his girl friend's house, where his rival, the obnoxious and rich Jerry Rudd, is visiting:

> "Why did I bother to apologize?" he grumbled to himself. "A man only makes a fool of himself when he does that."
>
> He was over Rosemead Airport, but his own rain was still raining there and it was an excuse for not going in. He crossed Los Angeles and Hollywood and Cahuenga Pass, and gave Sid his last observations. Not that he had to, but he liked to do his share in filling out Sid's maps. The fact that his sweep brought him over Patty Vernier's house was strictly coincidence.
>
> A lot of good stuff had collected over the San Fernando Valley—not heavily, but in patches, thanks to those two disturbing cold barriers he had precipitated. Studio City, where Patty lived, was obscured. On impulse, he slanted down and crossed her house at three hundred feet, both engines running.
>
> At this level, he could see clearly. There was Jerry Rudd's big red convertible, parked familiarly in the driveway. There was Mrs. Vernier, hanging out her washing, and Jerry was helping her. Jerry was very democratic at all times, of course. What fun a millionaire had, helping his inferiors with their chores! Bill gritted his teeth.

He gives Jerry a soaking:

> He went back to Van Nuys, turned, and tripped the trigger of his last magazine as he crossed the valley toward Cahuenga Pass, slowly. He went up and stayed there awhile, chuckling and ignoring the frantic buzzing of his phone. Patty had a sense of humor. Patty would see the joke. Patty was on his side again! He felt good. He'd get some sleep and call her later in the day, and they'd laugh together over how it looked from down there.
>
> From up here it looked good. He had hit it hard, and what moisture there was in the formation came down hard and sudden. It cleared up enough, in ten minutes, for him to see plainly through his binoculars.
>
> There was Mrs. Vernier, in person, galloping toward the house with the last of her starched white linens, getting them in, of course, just as the rain stopped. She'd have to starch them again—perhaps even wash them again. He hoped.
>
> There was Jerry Rudd, in sodden white flannels, letting Mrs. Vernier rescue her own wash, while he set a new record getting the top up on his convertible. He was quite a boy at hanging out laundry, but not so good at getting it in. Bill might have some explaining to do to Mrs. Vernier, but so would Jerry. After all, he ordered the precipitation.

Comment: Apart from my upvote and check mark, I feel compelled to make this completely redundant and deprecated remark expressing my gratitude for your knowledge and the time and effort you spent to disseminate it -- I'm sitting here smiling and happy and think *this* is how the internet should be :-). In this vein, thank you Joel, too. Your concept of public communication is more productive and sustainable than Mark's.

Comment: I would never deprecate a comment that says something nice about me. Praise me all you want, I can take it! :-)

Comment: do i get it right and the story has some sort of mobile phones as well??

Comment: @Gnudiff Mobile phones? I don't think so. The story mentions that Bill has a car phone: "He took their calls on his auto telephone en route to the airport." I suppose the telephone in his airplane was something like that. I don't think he would have an "auto telephone" if he had a mobile phone. I believe car phones were available when the story was written. Not sure about airplane telephones.

Comment: @Gnudiff You can read the whole story for yourself. The 1949 magazine in which it first appeared is available at the Internet Archive; I added a link to my answer.